# How to disable module wrapping for one file only

Tags: configuration, brunch

I want to avoid the `<script>require('app')<script>` on my index.html, how can I achieve this?

I think with a regex, but I'm not very skilled with them and the docs about the config are not so clear to me...

Comment: Did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `module.wrapper` section.

```
modules:
  wrapper: (path, data) ->
    return "#{data}" if /jquery/i.test(path) or /vendor/i.test(path) or /node_modules/i.test(path)
    moduleName = exports.config.modules.nameCleaner(path.replace(new RegExp('\\\\', 'g'), '/')).replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    'require.register("' + moduleName + '", function(exports, require, module) {\n' + data + '\n});\n\n'
```

That simulates commonjs wrapper on brunch 1.7.13. it doesnt wrap `jquery`,`vendor`,`node_modules` modules and wrap all others.

moduleName is cleared using code copy/pasted from brunch source code. I did not found way to reuse that code. You can always copy/paste it from `node_modules\brunch\lib\helpers.js:cleanModuleName` and `node_modules\brunch\lib\helpers.js:getModuleWrapper` functions

Returned string may be created with comparison tool. I just compared code generated with custom function and with standard function and made them similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it simply using the `modules` config. 
See the example below:

```
module.exports = config:
  modules:
    definition: false
    wrapper: false
files:
  javascripts: joinTo: 'app.js'
  stylesheets: joinTo: 'app.css'
```

This way your JavaScript file will be kept as is.